# How to set separate validation for each EditText in android?

Tags: java, android

I have 3 EditText view i my android project. I've set validation for all EditText and they display a Toast when any one of them is empty. What i want is, to set different toast for every EditText. For example if first EditText is empty it should say first is empty and so on.

**Here is my code :**

```
if(firstValue.getText().toString().isEmpty() | secondValue.getText().toString().isEmpty() | thirdValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
Toast.makeText(mainactivity.this, "Please enter all fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: create 3 different If statements

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is good way. Try this

```
    if(firstValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        setToast("firstValue message");
        return;
    }
    if(secondValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        setToast("secondValue message");
        return;
    }
    if(thirdValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        setToast("thirdValue message");
        return;
    }
```

Create method

```
    public void setToast(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(activity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: `""+msg` is the same as just doing `msg`, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. Both are same.

Comment: might as well just have it as `msg` then, seeing as the `""+` seems strange/is redundant

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way but to check each and every `EditText`. You can implement it in many different ways but the most simple is:

```
if(firstValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(mainactivity.this, "Please enter value into the first field!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

if(secondValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(mainactivity.this, "Please enter value into the second field!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

if(thirdValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(mainactivity.this, "Please enter value into the third field!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Note: you need to use `return;` if you want to stop further validation of inputs. Otherwise, remove `return;` and use `else if` statement.

Comment: very sensible answer with the inclusion of the `return;`, perhaps not necessary but a nice thing to include in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Simple make a function whih a edittext argument Example :

```
void validateEditText(EditText editText){
    if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        if (editText==firstValue){
            Toast.makeText(mainactivity.this, "First Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (editText==secondValue){
            Toast.makeText(mainactivity.this, "Second Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like an icon to appear in the same edittext that throws the error:

```
if(firstValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    firstValue.setError("Please enter value into the first field!");
    return;
}

if(secondValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    secondValue.setError("Please enter value into the second field!");
    return;
}

if(thirdValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    thirdValue.setError("Please enter value into the third field!");
    return;
}
```

Or a combination of setError() with Toast.

Comment: How do we set custom icon ?

Comment: By default, the setError method draws a red alert icon on the editText (or other element) causing the error. But you can also use your own icon like this: setError("custom error text", YOUR_DRAWABLE_ICON);

Comment: At least I have used it in editText, TextView... and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass list of EditTexts and show toast and return false if any of them is empty.

```
Boolean validateEditTexts(List<EditText> editTexts) {
    for(EditText editText: editTexts) {
        if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            String name = editText.getResources().getResourceEntryName(editText.getId());
            Toast.makeText(this, name + "is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can call above function by

```
Boolean allNotEmpty = validateEditTexts(new List<EditText>(view.findViewById(R.id.tvOne), view.findViewById(R.id.tvTwo)))
```